# How to force Plunker Editor to update an angular library dependency?

Tags: npm, editor, updates

I'm using Plunker Editor to show demos. My demo is an angular 2 project with my opensource npm package called `ng-ui-application` which is already published.
It worked when I bound the npm package in the `config.js`.

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {

    'app': './src',

    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',
    'ng-ui-application': 'npm:ng-ui-application'
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ng-ui-application': {
      main: './index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is when I published an update of `ng-ui-application` on https://www.npmjs.com/, the Plunker Editor doesn't get this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...
I changed in `config.js`

```
map: {

    'app': './src',

    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',
    'ng-ui-application': 'npm:ng-ui-application'
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ng-ui-application': {
      main: './index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
```

By this :

```
map: {

    'app': './src',

    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',
    'ng-ui-application': 'npm:ng-ui-application/index.js' <--- here !
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
   <--- I deleted it !
  }
```